# How to delete data from an RDBMS using Talend ELT jobs?

Tags: talend, sql-delete

What is the best way to delete from a table using Talend?

I'm currently using a tELTJDBCoutput with the action on Delete.

It looks like Talend always generate a `DELETE ... WHERE EXISTS (<your generated query>)` query.

So I am wondering if we have to use the field values or just put a fixed value of 1 (even in only one field) in the tELTmap mapping.

To me, putting real values looks like it useless as in the where exists it only matters the Where clause.

Is there a better way to delete using ELT components?

My current job is set up like so:

[image: Job layout]

The tELTMAP component with real data values looks like:

[image: tELTMap component with real data values]

But I can also do the same thing with the following configuration:

[image: tELTMap component with hard coded expressions]

Am I missing the reason why we should put something in the fields?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Your question is too localised but also missing key information about your intent. Are you trying to delete all of the data in a table (eg. truncate it) or are you trying to delete certain rows? If just certain rows then how are you identifying the rows you want to delete?

Comment: Send your images to my mail address and I will insert them into the question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am trying to delete some rows from a table in an ELT job. I would like to know if there is a best way and the intended usage of the fields inside the tELTMap component.
I could write the SQL expression and paste it into some tJDBCrow component to execute it, but that will move away from Talend "idiom".

Comment: @MarcusRickert OK I could not find how to send you an email to you :( Just opened an HAngout and shared the IMGs there.

Comment: My mail address is in my SO profile.

Comment: You should be able to link to any image host and someone can then edit your post to put them inline.

Comment: I've edited those images so they're linked in line now. I'll try and get around to a more specific answer some time tonight or tomorrow unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: TY @ydaetskcoR. My job is up and working, my question is if this is the right approach to ELT delete or am I missing something?
I feel strange to be able to put values / choose columns where they are not used, as the two produce the same results (the fixed value being probably faster).

Comment: @RobMcZag - yes your conclusion is right that you can even use 1 or 'A' kind of text in field mapping. It is only used by talend in delete from where exists (select 1 from...)...Which is correct and works..so what is your problem here? you do not necessary need to put something from source table in the field. you can very well do with hardcoded value..its just for inner select exists statement.

Comment: @garpitmzn my problem is to know if this is the right way to use it. I am confused from being able to put values in the interface and they being useless.
As this is strange I was wondering if there is another way to make deletes in ELT (besides writing the SQL in a tXXXrow).
I could say I was looking for the "best practice" in ELT deletes. Would you advise changing the question title?

Comment: best option to delete depends on how you want to..if you go with option as below t*db*input--->t*db*output and select delete option based on key - it will work too,..only problem is that for each row it will fire a delete statement kind of or in batch..where was delete from table where exists would be a single delete statment to be parsed by DB engine..and could be faster at times...

Answer (score 0):

### **The following answer is a demonstration of how to perform deletes using ETL operations where the data is extracted from the database, read in to memory, transformed and then fed back into the database. After clarification, the OP specifically wants information around how this would differ for ELT operations**

If you need to delete certain records from a table then you can use the normal database output components.

In the following example, the use case is to take some updated database and check to see which records are no longer in the new data set compared to the old data set and then delete the relevant rows in the old data set. This might be used for refreshing data from one live system to a non live system or some other usage case where you need to manually move data deltas from one database to another.

We set up our job like so:

[image: Job layout]

Which has two tMySqlConnection components that connect to two different databases (potentially on different hosts), one containing our new data set and one containing our old data set.

We then select the relevant data from the old data set and inner join it using a tMap against the new data set, capturing any rejects from the inner join (rows that exist in the old data set but not in the new data set):

[image: tMap configuration]

We are only interested in the key for the output as we will delete with a WHERE query on this unique key. Notice as well that the key has been selected for the `id` field. This needs to be done for updates and deletes.

And then we simply need to tell Talend to delete these rows from the relevant table by configuring our tMySqlOutput component properly:

[image: tMySqlOutput configuration]

Alternatively you can simply specify some constraint that would be used to delete the records as if you had built the DELETE statement manually. This can then be fed in as the key via a main link to your tMySqlOutput component.

For instance I might want to read in a CSV with a list of email addresses, first names and last names of people who are opting out of being contacted and then make all of these fields a key and connect this to the tMySqlOutput and Talend will generate a DELETE for every row that matches the email address, first name and last name of the records in the database.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, but that's ETL, I am looking how to do the best way in ELT (Transformations on the DB, made in SQL). If you have to work on millions of lines with multiple joins the ETL way is too slow.

Comment: @RobMcZag Then if you need something more complicated I need to see how you're generating the id's that need to be deleted. As I commented on the question if you can host screenshots of your job layout and configuration of key components and then link to them in the question then we can better help you in your specific use case.

Comment: it is not more complicated, it just is a different paradigm. In ETL you work in Java on data that is local, while in ELT you load the "bulk data" on the DB and then use SQL to manipulate it. The talend ELT components generate SQL code to be executed on the DB server from the java code run on the job server.

Comment: Yeah I know what ELT is but I don't know how you are getting the records you wish to delete and what you're currently doing. Without knowing this it's pretty hard to work out whether there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Right, I can not post the images in the question :(. I added them from dropbox, now.
I read country and user id from one table and delete based on that from the other. I feel that the DELETE operation in ELT is implemented in a not very clear way in Talend.
So I started to think that maybe I didn't understood how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example shown in your question:

[image: First example from OP's question]

you are specifically only selecting (for the deletion) products where the `SOME_TABLE.CODE_COUNTRY` is equal to `JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY` and `SOME_TABLE.FK_USER` is equal to `JS_OPP.FK_USER` in your where clause and then the data you send to the delete statement is setting the `CODE_COUNTRY`  equal to `JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY` and `FK_USER`  equal to `JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY`.

If you were to put a tLogRow (or some other output) directly after your tELTxMap you would be presented with something that looks like:

```
.----------+---------.
|      tLogRow_1     |
|=-----------+------=|
|CODE_COUNTRY|FK_USER|
|=-----------+------=|
|GBR         |1      |
|GBR         |2      |
|USA         |3      |
'------------+-------'
```

In your second example:

[image: Second example from OP's question]

You are setting `CODE_COUNTRY` to an integer of `1` (your database will then translate this to a VARCHAR `"1"`). This would then mean the output from the component would instead look like:

```
.------------.
|tLogRow_1   |
|=-----------|
|CODE_COUNTRY|
|=-----------|
|1           |
|1           |
|1           |
'------------'
```

In your use case this would mean that the deletion should only delete the rows where the `CODE_COUNTRY` is equal to "1".

You might want to test this a bit further though because the ELT components are sometimes a little less straightforward than they seem to be.

Comment: sorry to disagree, the deletion is the same in both cases (tested).
The generated SQL is something like 
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE EXISTS { select 1 from xxx where SOME_TABLE.CODE_COUNTRY = JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY and SOME_TABLE.FK_USER = JS_OPP.FK_USER }

So if I generate "select 1 from " or "select JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY, JS_OPP.FK_USER from " the deletion does not change, as the only thing that matters is the where clause.

What confuses me is that Talend is not using that extra info (JS_OPP.CODE_COUNTRY, JS_OPP.FK_USER ), but allowing me to enter it!